# How to link controls, Mind Mapping style

Tags: delphi, vcl, mindmap

I am trying to create a Mind Mapping look for an application I'm working on, where I need to link boxes with lines or arrows.

This is what I have so far:

[image: What I have so far]

And this is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

I can move and resize the boxes around, but after days of trials and research, I just can't figure out how to have the user add links to the boxes and have the lines recalculated and change their angles/lengths when the user moves the boxes around.

Even though part of this app uses Direct2D, I do not want to start rendering the boxes myself, due to time constraint.

I was going to revert to a less visual TreeView using VirtualTreeView, but I wish I could get this to work.

Can someone provide tips on how to accomplish this or know of existing components I could use?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming those are 3 controls? If so, I suggest not using controls, and do pure drawing yourself, for example in a paint box. Otherwise, you will have to rely on drawing these lines on the controls' parent most likely - either that or come up with some real messy solution. If a line crosses paths with another box, should the line show over or under that box?

Comment: Yup, they are indeed custom controls. I went that way thinking it would be easier to make since the boxes need to be moved/resized. If I cannot find a way, I'll turn to rendering them myself. Thanks, Jerry.

Comment: Think you'll need to do the drawing yourself.  I'd think at least you'd want something like a host container (`TPanel` derivative, etc) that could be aware of, manage, and draw the link relationships; also perhaps a custom linkable control that exposes its linkable-ness to the host...

Comment: Not sure if it's helpful or not, but you might want to check out TMS Diagram Studio for a ready-made solution.

Comment: Why would you need length/angle? You can have lines drawn by supplying end points only. Let the user select a hotspot in one of the linkable controls and drag the mouse to a hotspot in another linkable control. And store linked hotspots in some container. And draw lines between them.

Comment: Controls for the boxes is a bad idea. You need to separate the model from the visualisation.

Answer (score 1):

As Sertac Akyus sad in comments all you need is two reference points to be able to draw a line.

And you can simply go and draw a line on the canvas of the parents controll of your boxes using LineTo command.

If we take a look at your example. Drawing a line between Box1 and Box2 can be done using folowing procedure:

```
//Move point to the bottom midle of the Box1
Parent.Canvas.MoveTo(Box1.Left+(Box1.Width div 2),Box1.Top+Box1.Height);
//Draw a line to the top middle of the Box2
Parent.Canvas.LineTo(Box2.Left+(Box2.Width div 2),Box2.Top);
```

Now you need to pay special attention which of your controlls is higher so that your line doesen't necessarily cross it buzt instead only leads to its border.

You could even make life yourself a bit easier by simply drawing line from the center point of one box to the center point of another box like so

```
//Move point to the center of first box
Parent.Canvas.MoveTo(Box1.Left+(Box1.Width div 2),Box1.Top+(Box1.Height div 2));
//Draw a line to the center point of second box
Parent.Canvas.LineTo(Box2.Left+(Box2.Width div 2),Box2.Top+(Box2.Height div 2));
```

But this might not look as good as first aproach would.

Anywhay with mind graphs sooner or later you would probably run into situation where drawing straight lines would not be god enough.

In such cases you would want to offer support for drawing curved lines (athleast drawing of S curves). With these you need to provide your user with the ability to adjust them propery so that they won't be crossing othe boxes. But that requires the ability for user to select specific line and then ajust certain properties of it.

Another advanced approach that you might want to use is automatic curve drawing. Such approach uses the pathfinding algroithm in the background to find multiple reference points representing posible line path and then the ability to render Catmul-Rom spines through these reference points.

Unfortunately I can't offer you any code examples for this advanced aproach as I'm still trying to implement it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going for drawing the arrows myself. What I did was to place a TImage under the controls, and draw arrows in between the control's anchor points.

Since this will be an in-house editor, there's no need for advanced drawing or line management.

I then decided to draw antialiased lines, which TCanvas does not support, so I installed Graphics32 and using LineToAS() the lines looked great.

But after looking at TMS Diagram Studio demo, the need to reinvent this wheel is fading. It seems as it contains everything I need and then some.

Thanks to all for the comment!